# Querying and grouping data by applying a specific filter

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, firebird1.5

I have the following table (sample only) containing the ID of a specific item and its respective production cost throughout a certain period of time (omitted in this case)

```sql
|   id | cost|
|------|-----|
| 1667 |  20 |
| 2000 |  25 |
| 2000 |  30 |
| 1667 |  35 |
| 3244 | 500 |
| 3244 |   0 |
| 3244 |  25 |
| 3244 |  26 |
| 9999 |  56 |
| 3814 | 526 |
| 9999 | 699 |
| 3814 |  13 |
```

I am trying to extract the maximum value of each specific ID and so far I have been successful. The output looks like that:

```sql
|   id |  cost |
|------|-------|
| 2000 |    30 |
| 1667 |    35 |
| 3244 |   500 |
| 3814 |   526 |
| 9999 |   699 |
```

The code I am using is:

```sql
 SELECT *
 FROM t1 WHERE (id,cost) IN 
 (SELECT id, max(cost)
 FROM t1
 GROUP BY id
 )
```

However, I want to apply additional filters before getting the max value since sometimes the costs are entered as 0 or the numbers are too high.

- Firstly, I want to exclude all ID's with price=0.
- Secondly, I want to exclude all prices that are higher than 2x3rd Quartile of the specific ID.

For example, if we take ID=3244, the process would look like this:

```sql
|   id |  cost |        |   id |  cost |        |   id |  cost |
|------|-------|        |------|-------|        |------|-------|
| 3244 |    500|        | 3244 |    500|        |      |       |
| 3244 |      0|        |      |       |        |      |       |
| 3244 |     25|        | 3244 |     25|        | 3244 |     25|
| 3244 |     26|        | 3244 |     26|        | 3244 |     26|
```

The number I would get for ID=3244 would be 26 and I want to repeat this process for each ID.

Comment: Could you please tell what is 2x3rd Quartile

Comment: By the statement **3rd quartile of the id** Do you mean for an `id = 1234` the 3rd quartile would be `3`

Comment: @Shankar I mean that if the specific row value is twice higher than the 3rd Quartile, I would like the query to exclude it, i.e the 3rd Quartile of id=3244 is 263 (excluding the 0); 500>263 so exclude 500.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: The 3rd quartile of each ID, in the case of id=3244, it is 263
I hope this makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Using this [definition](http://www.mathwords.com/t/third_quartile.htm)

> For a set of data, a number for which 75% of the data is less than
>   that number. The third quartile is the same as the median of the part
>   of the data which is greater than the median. Same as 75th percentile.

**[SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e72e/9)**

```
SELECT item.id, MAX(cost) cost
 FROM item
 JOIN (
      SELECT item.id, avg(cost) thirdQ
      FROM item
      JOIN (
              SELECT id, avg(cost) mean_cost
              FROM item
              WHERE cost <> 0
              GROUP BY id
           ) T1
        ON item.id = T1.id
      WHERE cost > mean_cost and cost <> 0
      GROUP BY item.id
     ) T2
  ON item.id = T2.id
 WHERE cost < T2.thirdQ
 GROUP BY item.id
```

**OUPUT**

```
|   id | cost |
|------|------|
| 1667 |   20 |
| 2000 |   25 |
| 3244 |   26 |
| 3814 |   13 |
| 9999 |   56 |
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the code. I tried it but I am running into the following error:
`Invalid token Dynamic SQL Error. SQL error code = -104. Token unknown - line 4, char 7. SELECT.`

Perhaps this is due to the fact that I am constrained to use Firebird 1.5

Comment: Sorry, as you can see work ok in the fiddle. I suggest you start with the most inner select and start adding code sections. My guess is maybe the way I create alias but looks very basic code. Good Luck